# E_FAIL COM error creating Silverlight User Control with Microsoft.LightSwitch.Client

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm attempting to follow the instructions to [create a reusable modal window](http://janvanderhaegen.wordpress.com/2012/06/05/creating-reusable-modal-screens-2/) in LightSwitch from Jan Van der Haegen's blog. However after I click to add a new Silverlight User Control to the Client, and input the xaml I'm met with errors. I reduced the code to the shortest section that gives me an error:

> HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

From the following xaml:

```
<shellUtils:ScreenChildWindow
    xmlns:shellUtils="clr-namespace:Microsoft.LightSwitch.Runtime.Shell.Framework;assembly=Microsoft.LightSwitch.Client">
</shellUtils:ScreenChildWindow>
```

I just installed Visual Studio 2012 in a virtual machine, created a new project, new Client Silverlight User Control, and tried the same code and received the same error.

I also receive it with this code and others referencing Microsoft.LightSwitch.Client:

```
<Framework:GroupBox
    xmlns:Framework="clr-namespace:Microsoft.LightSwitch.Presentation.Framework;assembly=Microsoft.LightSwitch.Client">
</Framework:GroupBox>
```

Comments on the blog seem to indicate others have this error but I haven't found a solution anywhere yet. I also see the same/similar on Stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016025/exception-error-hresult-e-fail-with-microsoft-lightswitch-visual-studio-2012-rc), but unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that's correct, just close the preview window. The XAML designer has a hard time rendering the control when referencing the LS assemblies. You can ignore these errors.

If you're seeing these errors elsewhwere please let me know and we can investigate.

Answer (score 1):

After scouring the internet for the slightest related issue, I discovered at least in my case **the design view errors can be entirely ignored**.

Even with the other errors I didn't mention:

> Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace
>   Microsoft.LightSwitch.Cosmopolitan.Presentation.Controls' that could
>   not be found.
>
> The type 'ctls:OverflowControl' was not found. Verify that you are not
>   missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have
>   been built.
>
> An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary
>   /Microsoft.LightSwitch.Cosmopolitan.Client;component/Presentation/Shells/BasicStyles.xaml"

The control works perfectly. All the assembly preferences are present, so I'm not sure why the designer claims otherwise.